# Sequelize: bulkUpdate and beforeValidate hook

Tags: sequelize.js

It seems that sequelize bulkUpdate (using "individualHooks:true") stops the whole bulk insert process when "beforeValidate" is rejected (a promise returns "reject" with error) for one of the records in the bulkInsert array.

Is it possible to continue with bulkInsert of rows even when beforeValidate fails / is rejected for one of the records passed to bulkInsert array ?